# Доступ к базе данных через SSH-туннель на C# MySQLClient

Tags: c#, mysql, ssh, sql

Использую обычный коннектор для доступа к удаленной базе данных, решил сделать доступ не на прямую, а через ssh туннель.

Тут сразу несколько вопросов, насколько критично будет без ssh, и вообще есть какие-то большие плюсы? Может ли провайдер отвергать запросы которые идут на прямую? Если да, то придется мне курить ssh. Но это нужно переписать много-много кода.

Так вот основной вопрос, можно как-то соединится с сервером mysql по 3306 порту, а потом вместо хоста, в строке подключения писать localhost? Как будто я нахожусь прямо на сервере...

Всем спасибо за ответы!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Тут сразу несколько вопросов, насколько критично будет без ssh, и вообще есть какие-то большие плюсы?

Если вам важно, чтобы ваш трафик к MySQL не подслушали, то ssh можно использовать. А можно использовать защищённый доступ на базе SSL.  MySQL Connector/NET поддерживает использование SSL, **не** поддерживает использование ssh-туннелей, однако в интернете [есть руководство как организовать такой туннель](http://georgelantz.com/2007/09/10/access-mysql-through-ssh-tunnel-in-a-windows-net-application/) с помощью [дополнительного компонента sharpSSH](http://www.tamirgal.com/blog/page/SharpSSH.aspx). Также можно использовать коммерческий продукт, например [Devart dotConnect for MySQL](http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/mysql/features.html). Там встроена внутренняя поддержка соединения через ssh.

> Может ли провайдер отвергать запросы которые идут на прямую?

Если речь идёт о хостинг-провайдере, то может. Зачастую у хостинг-провайдеров закрыт прямой доступ "снаружи" к MySQL, однако иногда есть возможность в панели управления задать IP-адрес(а) с которых можно беспрепятственно подключаться на 3306 порт к серверу MySQL.

> Так вот основной вопрос, можно как-то соединится с сервером mysql по 3306 порту, а потом вместо хоста, в строке подключения писать localhost? Как будто я нахожусь прямо на сервере...

Можно. Для этого существует программа mysql-proxy. Она запускается на вашем компьютере и подключается к MySQL серверу. А клиентские программы подключаются к mysql-proxy на localhost-е. [Подробнее...](http://linuxshare.ru/docs/mysql/mysql-proxy.html)